# Is it possible with mustache.js to map xml and use xpath routes like {{/root/Customer}}?

Tags: mustache, template-engine, nustache

Is it possible with mustache.js (or any other template engine) to map xml to template and use xpath routes like?

```
Hello {{/root/Customer}} 
You have won {{/root/Prise}}
```

It is interesting to have possibility to use exactly xpaht queries with filters and axes (what is impossible whith "Json routes").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that trick (for nushache) by implementing IDictionary.

```
public class RenderXpath : IDictionary<string,object> 
{
    XElement xElement;
    public RenderXpath(XElement xElement)
    {
        this.xElement = xElement;
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            string @value = "";
            var element = xElement.XPathSelectElement(((key as string)??"").Trim());
            if (element.Elements().Count() > 0)
                return new RenderXpath(element); // support loops
            if (element.Value != null)
                return element.Value;
            return @value;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // all other throws NotImplementedException
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The syntax is {{xmlDoc./License/Customer}}
Thanks to mustache there is no need to escape '/' char.

Comment: I don't get why there is so less available projects doing exactly this. Accessing data from an xml via xpath to fill plain text templates... Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In Nustache you can pass XmlElement as the data parameter to the Render object, so there is no need to créate an specialized Dictionary class. But {{/root/Customer}} will throw an exception because {{/ is reserved for closing groups, you must use {{(/root/Customer)}} or simply {{Customer}} and pass DocumentElement as the data parameter

Answer (score 1):

To not answer your question: I don't think mustache can do this out of the box.

While researching a similar problem (I'm not fixed on any template engine) i can spare some of my cents: Have a look a [jath](https://github.com/dnewcome/jath) and maybe extract further inspirations from [this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/444447-template-language-xpath-support-source-code-generation#post1695795) post.